# Aurelia typescript scroll to top of page

Tags: typescript, aurelia

How to scroll page top top or div/id element?

Method in viewmodel (.ts) called by click.delegate from view (.html) scroll page to top or to selectable div by id etc. By using window? if, how to inject window in aurelia/typescript?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? Your question is pretty unclear. Also, what have you tried already? http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-html-behaviors-introduction/3

Comment: Just answering the last question you asked, `window` is a global property in the browser, so you don't need to inject it. It's just there to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't got your question completely, however, here is how I scroll to the top of the page on each navigation. Perhaps this helps you.

I have a scroll function (`smoothScrollReset`) which gets an element (can be every element) and scrolls to that element based on a given function (e.g `linearTween()`, you can change scrolling behavior by exchanging this one). The element I scroll to is some container on the page.
Then, I add a post render pipeline step to the Aurelia router. All together:

Adding the pipeline step:

```
...
let appRouterConfig = config => {
  config.addPipelineStep('postRender', ScrollToTopStep);
};

this.router.configure(appRouterConfig);
...
```

The pipeline step itself:

```
export class ScrollToTopStep {
  run(instruction, next) {
    let element = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
    smoothScrollReset(element);
    return next();
  }
}
```

The scrolling function:

```
export function smoothScrollReset(element) {
  if (!element) {
    return;
  }

  const duration = 200;
  const scrollFrom = element.scrollTop;
  const diff = -scrollFrom;
  let startTime = null;
  let lastYOffset;
  let scrollLoop = (currentTime) => {
    let currentYOffset = element.scrollTop;
    if (!startTime) {
      startTime = currentTime - 1;
    }

    const timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
    if (lastYOffset) {
      if ((diff > 0 && lastYOffset > currentYOffset) ||
        (diff < 0 && lastYOffset < currentYOffset)) {
        return;
      }
    }

    lastYOffset = currentYOffset;
    element.scrollTop = linearTween(timeElapsed, scrollFrom, diff, duration);
    if (timeElapsed < duration) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollLoop);
    } else {
      element.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollLoop);
}

function linearTween(t, b, c, d) {
  return c * t / d + b;
}
```